# How to extract JSON element within an Arel query on Postgres (Rails 5.2.4)?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

I defined a helper to feed a drop down select field in a HTML form.
I have a quite simple query, except that the **name** field has the JSON data type. It contains a name translated in several languages:

```
{"en":"New", "fr":"Nouveau", "de":"Neue"}
```

With PostgreSQL, extracting the desired translation is strait forward. The case here is simple, and the **->>** operator, when passed the JSON key, returns directly a text data :

```
SELECT  parameters.id, 
parameters.code, 
parameters.sort_code, 
parameters.property, 
name ->> 'en' as name 
FROM dqm_app.parameters 
WHERE parameters.parameters_list_id = 3
```

I tried to reproduce the query with Arel syntax:

```
options = Parameter.
            select(:id, 
                   :code, 
                   :sort_code, 
                   :property, 
                   Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("name ->> 'en' as name")).
            where("parameters_list_id = ?", 3)
```

Unfortunately, even though the generated query is identical to the SQL query, this returns a null value for the **name** field, or no value if I omit the **as name** statement.

**Note**: When writing the query without Arel statement, the result is the same:

```
options = Parameter.
            select("id, code, sort_code, property, (name ->> 'en') as name").
            where("parameters_list_id = ?", 3)
```

I am suspecting that the model is waiting for a JSON data, but gets a text for the **name** field, and doesn't know how to manage it.
How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works for me in rails 5.2.4 and Postgres 13. But I am using a JSONB column. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: I am also able to shorten it to `... Arel.sql("name ->> 'en' as name")...`

Comment: What happens if you do `Parameter.find_by_sql("SELECT  parameters.id, parameters.code, parameters.sort_code, parameters.property, name ->> 'en' as name FROM dqm_app.parameters WHERE parameters.parameters_list_id = 3")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) documentation, extracting a text from a simple JSON uses the operator **->>** in the form:

> json ->> text → text
>
> jsonb ->> text → text
>
> Extracts JSON object field with the given key, as text.
>
> '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json ->> 'b' → 2

But in the case described above, where Rails expects a JSON field, the syntax that works is `name -> 'en'`. The value returned by this form has the JSON data type from the PostgreSQL point of view, and results in the expected String attribute after Rails processing the returned value.

The solution to my issue is:

```
options = Parameter.
            select("id, code, sort_code, property, (name -> 'en') as name").
            where("parameters_list_id = ?", 3)
```